# Cabal can't find foreign libraries

Tags: haskell, llvm, windows-10, ghc, cabal

Recently I was trying to install [llvm-general-3.5.1.0](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/llvm-general) package.. for about a week. Basically I am getting this error: [link](https://github.com/bscarlet/llvm-general/issues/156). My situation is identical. Windows 10, ghc 7.10.2, cabal 1.22.4.0. I installed llvm 3.5.2 from sources with cmake and everything went fine. In llvm/lib directory I have *.lib files (eg. LLVMAnalysis.lib).

But somehow cabal can't see those libraries and gives this frustrating error:

> Configuring llvm-general-3.5.1.0...
>   setup.exe: Missing dependencies on foreign libraries:
>   * Missing C libraries: LLVMLTO, LLVMObjCARCOpts, LLVMLinker, LLVMipo,
>   LLVMVectorize, LLVMBitWriter, LLVMCppBackendCodeGen, LLVMCppBackendInfo,
>   LLVMTableGen, LLVMDebugInfo, LLVMOption, LLVMX86Disassembler,
>   LLVMX86AsmParser, LLVMX86CodeGen, LLVMSelectionDAG, LLVMAsmPrinter,
>   LLVMX86Desc, LLVMX86Info, LLVMX86AsmPrinter, LLVMX86Utils, LLVMJIT,
>   LLVMIRReader, LLVMAsmParser, LLVMLineEditor, LLVMMCAnalysis,
>   LLVMMCDisassembler, LLVMInstrumentation, LLVMInterpreter, LLVMCodeGen,
>   LLVMScalarOpts, LLVMInstCombine, LLVMTransformUtils, LLVMipa, LLVMAnalysis,
>   LLVMProfileData, LLVMMCJIT, LLVMTarget, LLVMRuntimeDyld, LLVMObject,
>   LLVMMCParser, LLVMBitReader, LLVMExecutionEngine, LLVMMC, LLVMCore,
>   LLVMSupport
>   This problem can usually be solved by installing the system packages that
>   provide these libraries (you may need the "-dev" versions). If the libraries
>   are already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the
>   flags --extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where they are.

I really want to use this package on my Windows, but nothing seems to work (I tried everything like --extra-lib-dirs and compiled also with MinGW and VS - the same problem).

I can't accept the fact that it won't install. I mean, there must be some way to fix Setup.hs from this cabal package or something. Does anyone have an idea what can be wrong with cabal in this case and how can I try to workaround this? I don't know how exactly cabal works, maybe someone with this knowledge will have an idea? Or maybe there is a way to do this without cabal?

Comment: Did you read the entire issue? It's a [cabal bug](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/2887).

Comment: @Zeta, I didn't think it is considered a bug officially. There is no single reply in that thread. Are you saying that nothing can be done until this bug is fixed by cabal authors, and I can't install this package?

Comment: Since you're able to reproduce the error, a reply on the thread would raise some awareness. That being said, I don't know how many cabal devs use Windows 10. I'm currently on Linux, but I'll try to reproduce it on Win8 later.

Comment: Thank you @Zeta, that would be awesome.

Comment: Sorry, I had several problems with LLVM yesterday and wasn't able to get things working. Apparently, LLVM doesn't like my MinGW configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, i've managed to build it and, i think, found the root of the issue.

First, steps to build:

1. Get the MinGW. My installation of MinGW has gcc 4.8.
2. Get 32-bit MinGHC.
3. Compile LLVM 3.5 with MinGW's gcc and install it somewhere.
4. Copy contents of MinGW installation directory into `MinGHC Install
   Dir\ghc-7.10.2\mingw`, replacing conflict files.
5. In the command line set your PATH so it has haskell toolset from
   MinGHC (i recommend using switch .bat scripts) and llvm-config.exe.
6. Get the `llvm-general` package source either using `cabal fetch` or
   downloading via browser from hackage.
7. Replace `cc-options: -std=c++11` line of `llvm-general.cabal` with
   `cc-options: -std=gnu++11`.
8. Finally, `cabal configure` and `cabal build` should work.

I have been changing my build environment many times, so if this doesn't work for you let me know, i probably forgot something.

---

Now let's go into details.

What we thought is a bug of cabal is not, actually. The problem is that both `stack` and `MinGHC` (and `Haskell Platform`, i guess) use quite old `gcc` - 4.6. This gcc has even two defects:

- It doesn't support `-std=c++11` and LLVM 3.5 can't be built using it.
  As a consequence, this gcc can't be used by ghc when compiling
  llvm-general, because it can't parse LLVM headers properly.
- Even if it could, its linker can't link against LLVM libs compiled by
  MinGW using gcc 4.8. **This** is why cabal was telling you it
  couldn't find LLVM libs. I've hacked `Setup.hs` so that it wouldn't
  look for these libs, but pass `-lLLVMSomething` to linker via `-pgml`
  ghc option. This lead to clear error message:

  ```
  ld.exe: ignoring libLLVMSupport.a ...
  ld.exe: can't find -lLLVMSupport
  ```

So, the `cabal` **was** actually finding these libs, but was dropping them because they couldn't be linked to.

Ideally, the solution would be to update mingw distribution used by stack/MinGHC. But as a workaround you can just replace old gcc with new one.

Finally, `-std=gnu++11` is used because current MinGW release is [affected by this bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/2250/), which prevents compilation of c++ bits of the package. Whew, that was a long way.

Comment: Thank you! Today I noticed discrepancies between versions of gcc that I'm actually using and that is in Haskell Platform's directory. They were 4.8 and 4.6 respectively. And the latter was used for installing packages so obviously it couldn't work with llvm-general. I didn't know how to solve it and I followed you steps. And it installed this package! However, can you use it? I wrote simple hello world in Haskell with one additional import: 'import LLVM.General.Analysis'.

Comment: And it gave a lot of errors like: 'C:\LLVM\llvm-3.5.2/lib/libLLVMDebugInfo.a(DWARFDebugLine.o):(.text+0x74c): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned int)'' during compilation. So it ended with: 
'collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status'.
Am I missing something obvious, or there must be done some additional work to compile it?

Comment: I tried to compile with: 'ghc Main.hs --make'. Maybe I should add something to this command? Or rather there is still something not OK with this package?

Comment: This command with this program works on Ubuntu. So there must be still some problem with compilers that prevents me from using llvm-general package.

Comment: Yup, it works for me both with `ghc --make` or creating a whole new package that depends on llvm-general and `cabal build`ing it. You didn't delete MinGW directory when copying it over MinGHC by any chance?

Comment: What do you mean by deleting? I performed 4th step, so I overwrote those conflicting files in MinGHC dir. So now when I type 'gcc --version' in cmd I get '4.8' as desired. And this gcc is the only one in PATH variable. Should work. But doesn't this error 'C:\LLVM\llvm-3.5.2/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(raw_ostream.o):(.text+0x1c20): undefined reference to `__cxa_guard_release'' look like it is still using the old gcc or something? If it works for you then it must be some easy detail I forgot.

Comment: I was talking about source MinGW dir, the one where you were copying from. You should've used this MinGW to compile LLVM, too. Also, make sure you have `extra-libraries: stdc++` in llvm-general.cabal.

Comment: Nope, I left this original MinGW untouched. And I built LLVM with it. But now ghc uses this from MinGHC which is upgraded by copying from the original one. stdc++ was by default, I added -std=gnu++11 instead of -std=c++11.

Comment: I'm talking about `extra-libraries: stdc++` field, not `cc-options: -std=c++11`. Do you have it in `library` section of .cabal file?

Comment: Yes, it was by default. But maybe I just installed this package in a wrong way. I typed "cabal install llvm-general.cabal" in a folder with downloaded package. Should I try something else? But in my opinion sth is still not right with the compilers, something I missed. This link error looks like it is using gcc 4.6.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95785/discussion-between-arrowd-and-xan).